# Difference between "Mollify" and "Pacify"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Also, which word is suitable in a context of hunger?

Comment: What did the dictionary say which confused you?

Comment: On the difference, what have dictionaries told you? As to what synonym to use with *hunger,* try *assuage.*

Comment: The Google dictionary actually lists "Pacify" as a synonym for "Mollify".

Comment: I guess satiate is also a good word to use with hunger.

Comment: You have tagged this question with 'meaning-in-context' but have given us no context with which to work.

Comment: Context is hunger. Food mollifies/pacifies hunger. Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), which verges on being a general reference, though its online incarnation is Merriam-Webster Online, has this comment on *pacify* and *mollify*:

> PACIFY, APPEASE, PLACATE, MOLLIFY, PROPITIATE, CONCILIATE mean to ease the anger or disturbance of. PACIFY suggests a soothing or calming [example omitted]. ... MOLLIFY implies soothing hurt feelings or rising anger [example omitted].

James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Standard Handbook of Synonyms, Antonyms & Prepositions* (1947) classifies both words as members of the *allay* family:

> *Pacify* and *appease* signify to bring peace; to *mollify* is to soften; ...

From these two treatments, I would infer that *pacify* may apply to a broader range of objects (a horse, for example) than *mollify* does, *mollify* being specific to people.

---

As for using either term with *hunger*, I agree with JeffSahol's answer that neither *pacify* nor *mollify* is particularly apt, though *pacify* could work in a metaphorical sense. A very simple alternative that does work is *lessen*.

Answer (score 1):

"Mollify" carries more of a connotation of appeasement (as opposed to actual easing of the source of conflict) than "pacify".

Neither is a great choice with hunger, though that's more my opinion...I'd say "quell" if you're trying to indicate that hunger is being handled by eating a substantial meal, or "appease" if it's just a candy bar or some kind of snack to temporarily satisfy hunger.

Answer (score 0):

**Mollify** - to mitigate or reduce

**Pacify** - to restore to peace or order, esp by the threat or use of force

- peace- to be or become silent or still

Between the two **mollify** would actually lessen the, in this case, hunger while **pacify** would simply cause it to be less noticeable by dampening the signals with regard to hunger without actually reducing the cause. Eating **mollifies** hunger, chewing gum or drinking water **pacifies** it.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pacify
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mollify
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peace

Comment: Can you cite any sources to back this up?